# How to find the leaky faucet that loads into Malloc 32kb

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, avaudioplayer

I have been messing around with Leaks trying to find which function is not being deallocated (I am still new to this) and could really use some experienced insight.

I have this bit of code that seems to be the culprit.  Every time I press the button that calls this code, 32kb of memory is additionally allocated to memory and when the button is released that memory does not get deallocated.

What I found was that everytime that `AVAudioPlayer` is called to play an m4a file, the final function to parse the m4a file is `MP4BoxParser::Initialize()` and this in turn allocates 32kb of memory through `Cached_DataSource::ReadBytes`

My question is, how do I go about deallocating that after it is finished so that it doesn't keep allocating 32kb every time the button is pressed?

Any help you could provide is greatly appreciated!

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

//stop playing
theAudio.stop;


// cancel any pending handleSingleTap messages 
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleSingleTap) object:nil];

UITouch* touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject]; 


NSString* filename = [g_AppsList objectAtIndex: [touch view].tag];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: filename ofType:@"m4a"];  
theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];  
theAudio.delegate = self; 
[theAudio prepareToPlay];
[theAudio setNumberOfLoops:-1];
[theAudio setVolume: g_Volume];
[theAudio play];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to memory management in Cocoa is to balance out any calls to `alloc`, `retain` or `copy` with a subsequent call to `release`.

In this case, you are sending `alloc` to initialize your `theAudio` variable, but you are never sending `release`.

Assuming that you will only have one sound playing at a time, the best way to do this is with a property on your controller (the one that has this `-touchesBegan` method). The property declaration would look like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer * theAudio;
```

You will then need to set `theAudio` to `nil` in your `init` method:

```
theAudio = nil; // note: simple assignment is preferable in init
```

And be sure to release the variable in your `dealloc` method:

```
[theAudio release];
```

Now, your `touchesBegan` could look like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    //stop playing
    theAudio.stop;
    ...
    AVAudioPlayer * newAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfUrl:...];
    self.theAudio = newAudio; // it is automatically retained here...

    theAudio.delegate = self; 
    [theAudio prepareToPlay];
    [theAudio setNumberOfLoops:-1];
    [theAudio setVolume: g_Volume];
    [theAudio play];

    [newAudio release];       // ...so you can safely release it here
}
```

Comment: could you explain which `init` method you are referring to?  (again, sorry i am very new to this)

Comment: and also, just to verify I understand this:  What you are saying is that I need to load the audio into an additional allocated variable so that I'm not trying to deallocate the current m4a file (or eventually call a deallocated piece of memory)

I guess my question is, will `theAudio` still allocate additional memory each time since it isn't being dellocated until `dealloc()` is called?

Comment: Normally speaking, every controller has both an `-init` and a `dealloc` method. Can I assume that this as a `UIViewController`? If so, the proper method to override is -initWithNibName:bundle: Another alternative is to set your ivar to nil in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: To answer your second question: the line `self.theAudio = newAudio` takes care of a lot of "magic" behind the scenes. It actually calls `dealloc` on the old object before assigning (and retaining) the new one. This ensures that any memory that was allocated for the old instance is freed.

Comment: The final call to `release` in your `dealloc` method is simply there to release the very last object that was stored in the ivar, at the point when your controller itself is released.

Comment: If you're looking for a better understanding of this stuff, Apple has a really good introductory document: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html
A lot of the Cocoa questions here on SO involve memory leaks, so it is definitely recommended reading `:)`

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for taking the time to really detail it so I could understand!  I got rid of that one and onto a few others now on my own :)

Answer (score 1):

This line looks culprit to me:

```
theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
```

When does this resource get released?